# Python: get index out of a dictionary

Tags: python, indexing

I have the following problem:

```
test={
'Testuser':{'tap1':1,'tap2':1}
}

def testfunc(prefs,person)
    print prefs[person]
```

This function would give me:

```
{'tap1':1,'tap2':1}
```

But I only want `'tap1', 'tap2'` as the output.

What would be a good way to get this?

Comment: `prefs[person].keys()`? Use IPython's auto-complete feature, it's a _lot_ of help when discovering the language!

Comment: Reminder: because dictionaries are unordered, anything you do to get keys out could give you `'tap2', 'tap1'` as easily as `'tap1', 'tap2'`.  Be prepared to sort them if you have a preferred order.

Answer (score 4):

`prefs[person]` is a dictionary, so you can use the `keys()` method to get all the keys for that person:

```
print prefs[person].keys()
```

(Note, I changed your title and tags because there are no lists or arrays involved here at all.)

Answer (score 1):

Use the `keys()` method:

```
dict.keys()
```